# Security update failed : The baseline msi is not installed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation, service-pack

Yesterday we had to apply a security update for SQL Server 2008 SP4(
Current version: 10.0.6000.29) (from [KB3045311](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3045311) and [MS15-058](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms15-058.aspx)) and it failed in both the nodes of a Windows failover cluster and both the nodes are of the same version. The log files only say this:

> 2015-10-21 02:26:29 Slp: Patch Id KB3045311_sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64 - NotInstalled on the baseline msi package sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64.  Detail description of this patch package is: PatchId=KB3045311_sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64 PatchVersion=10.4.6241.0 BaselinePackageId=sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64 BaselineVersion=10.4.6000.29; PatchFileName=sql_engine_core_inst.msp PatchCode={511E22C9-E550-4C68-994B-AA3F388A4E2F}
>   
> 2015-10-21 02:26:29 Slp: Patch Id: KB3045311_sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu32 - The baseline msi is not installed. The patch package is ignored. 
>   
> [...many more of these for different patchIds and clsids...]

The application event logs has this:

> Product: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Database Engine Services - Update
>    '{511E22C9-E550-4C68-994B-AA3F388A4E2F}' could not be installed. Error 
>    code 1642.

However, the security update for SQL Server 2012 did go through fine which was done at the same time.

Any thoughts about why the SQL Server 2008 SP4 security update is failing?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I reviewed this a bit further and another cause of this issue has been the Windows Installer cache.  That seems to create a 'file not found' error when looking for the copy of the msi/msp package that's copied into the Windows directory with the update GUID.  We're not seeing that here, but I think it's because we're not seeing the actual log file for the KB.  Aaron's point was good to bypass Windows Update, but also check to see if everything actually exists where it is supposed to if that doesn't work.
Check [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlstuff/archive/2009/11/11/how-to-put-the-installer-cache-back-together-for-sql-following.aspx) for that solution to this issue.  Again, we will know much better when we can get the actual log.

This has came up a few times in prior versions of MS SQL Server.  [This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqljourney/archive/2012/04/03/sql-2005-setup-fails-with-1642-unable-to-install-windows-installer-msp-file.aspx) shows a good way to actually troubleshoot and resolve the issue. His solution of copying a exe from the other node and replacing it in the binn folder then restarting seems too hacky for me.  I like the SQLGuru suggestion of just reinstalling the prior SP.  That might give you some good results.

This problem can be caused by several issues such as using the wrong patch (x64 vs x32, wrong sp cu, etc.) and other scenarios such as the one listed where the version of the exe for whatever reason isn't what it is expecting, or a entry is not found for that patch in the registry, or God knows what else.  I don't.

The best way to really see what is the root underlying issue would be to review the log files for that particular KB.  It should be in the same section as your other log file you pasted.  From there you should be able to note if the actual patch is the wrong one or out of order, if you need to just reinstall the prior SP and then retry, or if there's another error you'll need to address.  The actual log for those should be named something like sqlversion_KB#.log

Comment: Thanks for all the response.We will try applying it manually ..

Comment: I don't see any log file like sqlversion..All that is there is Summary_Nodename_20151021_022550.txt ,detail.txt in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151021_022550

Comment: Hmm that's odd.  It shouldn't say the words 'sqlversion' but something similar to SQL10_KB3045311 as an example.  If it's not there, I'm not sure if the details.txt will help, you might be better off trying one of the workarounds and seeing if the files actually exist.  Aaron gave some great points to check which I'd probably start with.  Let us know.

Comment: Thanks Ali.Unfortunately we won't be trying this till our next rotation of the downtime comes for this server,but will let you know the result when it happens.Thanks both of you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

From the error messages in the summary log, it seems like the baseline MSIs could not be found (perhaps because you cleaned out `C:\Windows\Installer`?).

I would suggest:

1. Installing [the QFE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48016) instead of the GDR (this will attempt to patch you to 10.0.6535, giving you this security fix and a couple of other fixes [described here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3034373)).
2. **Not** using Windows Update, but rather applying the patch manually. This may bypass whatever problem Windows Update is having finding the baseline MSIs, and if not, may give you better error messages interactively.
3. Investigating the log file with the KB article number in the file name, as @Ali suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with this patch for SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 (Version: 10.53.6000.34), but maybe I found the root cause for this.

There are multiple checks for the baseline package and version during the setup routine. While all others succeed to find the right values, the check on the line prior the line you posted was the culprit.
My log file had the following:

> **2016-09-19 16:57:26 Slp: Patch Id: KB3045316_sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64 - The baseline msi is not installed.  The patch package is ignored.**
>   2016-09-19 16:57:26 Slp: Patch Id: KB3045316_sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64 - Detail description of this patch package is: PatchId=KB3045316_sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64 PatchVersion=10.53.6220.0 BaselinePackageId=sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64 BaselineVersion=10.53.6000.34; PatchFileName=sql_engine_core_inst.msp PatchCode={C83DA2A5-0249-4330-A786-B5E1650FB6AB}

It looks like the check is performed with help of Windows Installer service and full restrictions for a minor upgrade patch, which means the product code of the un-transformed baseline package must match the target code of the patch. In my special case it was {93A57276-C398-4E0C-9D08-B02815E19AD4} for the product code and {13E296DD-0186-4DE3-8133-145C1A3EC691} for the target code:
[image: sql_patch_error.png]
Because the Windows Installer service was used for the check you get the errors on the application event log if something goes wrong.

So far so bad. Now it comes to the strange part.

The setup routine just ignores the last check and continues to install this patch file by manual instructing the Windows Installer service how to apply it (lower restrictions for the QFE patch).
Here is the log for this part:

> MSI (s) (14:74) [17:03:22:857]: SequencePatches starts. Product code: {FBD367D1-642F-47CF-B79B-9BE48FB34007}, Product version: 10.50.1600.1, Upgrade code: {1CBCA79C-7BD0-4F4F-B927-EED77B249CE1}, Product language 1033
>   MSI (s) (14:74) [17:03:22:857]: PATCH SEQUENCER: verifying the applicability of minor upgrade patch {783E8847-EE12-4DB3-969A-15490E01B24E} against product code: {FBD367D1-642F-47CF-B79B-9BE48FB34007}, product version: 10.50.1600.1, product language 1033 and upgrade code: {1CBCA79C-7BD0-4F4F-B927-EED77B249CE1}
>   MSI (s) (14:74) [17:03:22:857]: PATCH SEQUENCER: minor upgrade patch {783E8847-EE12-4DB3-969A-15490E01B24E} is applicable.
>   MSI (s) (14:74) [17:03:22:857]: PATCH SEQUENCER: verifying the applicability of QFE patch d:\358e4ddee3e7f3f7544485bf548c\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\sql_engine_core_inst.msp against product code: **{93A57276-C398-4E0C-9D08-B02815E19AD4}**, product version: 10.53.6000.34, product language 1033 and upgrade code: {1CBCA79C-7BD0-4F4F-B927-EED77B249CE1}
>   MSI (s) (14:74) [17:03:22:857]: PATCH SEQUENCER: QFE patch d:\358e4ddee3e7f3f7544485bf548c\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\sql_engine_core_inst.msp **is applicable**.
>   MSI (s) (14:74) [17:03:22:857]: SequencePatches returns success.
>   MSI (s) (14:74) [17:03:22:857]: Final Patch Application Order:
>   MSI (s) (14:74) [17:03:22:857]: {783E8847-EE12-4DB3-969A-15490E01B24E} - 
>   MSI (s) (14:74) [17:03:22:857]: {C83DA2A5-0249-4330-A786-B5E1650FB6AB} - d:\358e4ddee3e7f3f7544485bf548c\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\sql_engine_core_inst.msp
>   ...
>   MSI (s) (14:74) [17:03:31:217]: Product: SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Database Engine Services -- Configuration completed successfully.

In other words:

The setup routine produces ugly errors in the logs, but the installation succeeds without errors.